# DirectX: Drawing a cube from struct array

Tags: c++, directx, render, game-engine, cube

I'm creating a game and was looking to draw a cube in window. I completed a working function that fills a `VERTEX` structure with an obj file's vertex content. However, passing the output structure into the buffer seems to output 1 to 2 visible vertices (under `D3D_PRIMITIVE_TOPOLOGY_POINTLIST`, for debugging purposes) while the entire structure is printable.

Since I'm passing in raw vertices, is there something else I need to know? 
(Using DX11)

(Triangles are drawn. Squares seem to draw a triangle.(Under `D3D_PRIMITIVE_TOPOLOGY_TRIANGLESTRIP`))

EDIT:

```
objv= GetObjData(FilePath, 1);
VERTEX *Cup = new VERTEX[objv.size()];
Cup = CreateVertexDS(objv, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
int Cupsize=objv.size();
ObjSz=Cupsize; //Debugging purposes, sets a global variable: # of array elements.
```

Vertice are brought in,

```
D3D11_BUFFER_DESC BufferDescription;
ZeroMemory(&BufferDescription, sizeof(BufferDescription));

BufferDescription.Usage                   =D3D11_USAGE_DYNAMIC;
BufferDescription.ByteWidth               =sizeof(VERTEX)*ObjSz; //# of element from obj file.
BufferDescription.BindFlags               =D3D11_BIND_VERTEX_BUFFER;
BufferDescription.CPUAccessFlags          =D3D11_CPU_ACCESS_WRITE;
BufferDescription.MiscFlags               =0;

D3D11_SUBRESOURCE_DATA SRData;
ZeroMemory(&SRData, sizeof(SRData));
SRData.pSysMem=&Cup;

    Compile_Monitor = Device->CreateBuffer(&BufferDescription, &SRData, &D3DBuffer);
    if(FAILED(Compile_Monitor))
{
   MessageBox(hWnd, L"CreateBuffer() failed. Check for: \n Possible Bad or NULL value in D3D11_BUFFER_DESC struct.", 
                    L"Program Error!", 
                    MB_OK);
   PostQuitMessage(0);
}
    D3D11_MAPPED_SUBRESOURCE MappedResource;
    Compile_Monitor = DeviceContext->Map(D3DBuffer, NULL, D3D11_MAP_WRITE_DISCARD, NULL, &MappedResource);
    if(FAILED(Compile_Monitor))
{
   MessageBox(hWnd, L"Map() failed.", 
                    L"Program Error!", 
                    MB_OK);
   PostQuitMessage(0);
}
    memcpy(MappedResource.pData, &Cup, sizeof(Cup));
    DeviceContext->Unmap(D3DBuffer, NULL);
}
```

Data is rendered:

```
void Render(){
float ColorBlue[] = {0.4f,0.4f,0.4f,1.0f};
DeviceContext->ClearRenderTargetView(RenderTargetView,ColorBlue);
    UINT stride=sizeof(VERTEX);
    UINT Offset=0;
    DeviceContext->IASetVertexBuffers(0,1,&D3DBuffer,&stride,&Offset);
    DeviceContext->IASetPrimitiveTopology(D3D_PRIMITIVE_TOPOLOGY_POINTLIST);    

DeviceContext->Draw(ObjSz,0);
Swapchain->Present(0,0);

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the problem is loading the obj file, check this out: http://rastertek.com/dx11tut08.html.  This particular example loads the data from an obj file and outputs it as its own file format, but the `ReadFileCounts` and `LoadDataStructures` functions combined should do exactly what you're looking for.  Just anything between `fin.close();` and `fout.close();` in `LoadDataStructures`.

If the problem is rendering the `VERTEX` structure, I'll need its code as well.

Comment: You sir, are clairvoyant and knowledgeable. Your link gives way to a brief description about vertex ordering: Maya's right handed coordinate system versus Directx format. I'm going to implement this in code and check out the results.

Comment: @InfinityMachine I've never been called clairvoyant before.  I'll have to look that up :)

Comment: @InfinityMachine "the ability to gain information about an object, person, location or physical event through means other than the known human senses,i.e., a form of extra-sensory perception." I dig it!